# Enhance SQLAlchemy syntax for polymorphic identity

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, metaclass

I have a declarative base class `Entity` which defines the column `name` as polymorphic, e.g.

```
class Entity(DeclarativeBase):
    name = Column('name', String(40))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on':name}
```

In subclasses, I could now say

```
class Experiment(Entity):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': "experiment"}
```

and be done. However, I would like to ease the creation of subclasses for the users of my library and therefore make the following possible:

- Have a better syntax for it which is not as convoluted as the default syntax. This could be a simple assignment `poly_id = "exp"` inside the class or maybe a class decorator.
- If no polymorphic_identity is given, extract the name from the name of the subclass.

I tried to get this done using metaclasses (only the second part):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta

class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_):
        dict_["__mapper_args__"] = {'polymorphic_identity': classname}
        return super(Meta, cls).__init__(classname, bases, dict_)

class CombinedMeta(Meta, DeclarativeMeta):
    pass

class Experiment(Entity):
    __metaclass__ = CombinedMeta
```

so that, in my opinion, my `Meta` should set the name before calling the `DeclarativeMeta` but it does not seem to work. So either the `DeclarativeMeta` which supposedly sets the polymorphic name never sees the change because I messed up the MRO or what I’m doing is plain wrong anyway. What would I need to change or is there even something like this in SQLAlchemy already?

Comment: When `__init__` is called, the class is already constructed. `__init__` is not a constructor. If you did this in `__new__`, it would work without problems. And you don't have to have so many metaclasses... just `class MyMeta(DeclarativeMeta): ...` and then instantiate your declarative base from MyMeta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shame on me but the problem could easily be solved by not using the `dict_` but by setting the attribute directly on `cls`.

```
class Meta(DeclarativeMeta):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kw):
        if getattr(cls, '_decl_class_registry', None) is None:
            return # they use this in the docs, so maybe its not a bad idea
        cls.__mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': cls.__name__}
        return super(Meta, cls).__init__(*args, **kw)

class Experiment(Entity):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
```

Answer (score 1):

Recent sqlalchemy docs show ways of using mixin classes for such purposes (I'm not sure whether it only works in versions >= 0.6 or if it is only better documented now)

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html

Comment: That does not really work in that form because it doesn’t allow me to dynamically set the `__mapper_args__`; it would just allow me to set a predefined `__mapper_args__` in all classes the mixin is used in.